# No result returned on ContourPlot with specific relation

Tags: plotting, complex

For reference, I am using Wolfram Mathematica 12.0. I am attempting to plot the complex subset defined by:
$|z+6|+|z-6| =1$ where z is a complex number $z = x+ i y$. Utilising ContourPlot directly like so:

```
ContourPlot[
 Abs[x + I y - 6] + Abs[x + I y + 6] == 1, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50},
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

gives me a blank screen. I then attempt to use ComplexExpand to plot:

```
ContourPlot[
 Sqrt[(-6 + x)^2 + y^2] + Sqrt[(6 + x)^2 + y^2] == 1, {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

which likewise returns nothing. Only by solving for x and y individually then plotting each branch separately like so:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  y /. Solve[ComplexExpand[Abs[x + I y - 6] + Abs[x + I y + 6] == 1], 
    y]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

gives me the hyperbola. What's going on here? Any other subset I plot using ContourPlot will return an appropriate relation with the exception of this. Is this a potential bug?

Comment: `Solve[Abs[z - 6] + Abs[z + 6] == 1, z] (* {} *) ` has no solution! That's why `ContourPlot`only shoes a blanc screen!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Sorry if I was being vague, but by z I meant the complex number $z = x + i y$

Comment: In my comment  I was vague too. Try `NMinimize[(Abs[x + I y + 6] + Abs[x + I y - 6] - 1)^2, {x, y}] (*{121., {x -> 0.215864, y -> 1.55783*10^-10}}*)` to show, that probably no solution exists.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Upon further inspection, you're right. Manually evaluating the expression by hand gives me something that cannot give any solutions, yet somehow Mathematica solves it somehow? Fascinating. Thank you

Comment: Because the `y` given by `Solve` is a complex number. If you ristrict the domain e.g. `Solve[ComplexExpand[Abs[x + I y - 6] + Abs[x + I y + 6] == 1], y, Reals]`, `Solve` will give `{}` as the output. I'm voting to close because this question arises due to a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an empty contour plot because the surface

```
z[x_, y_] = ComplexExpand[Abs[x + I y - 6] + Abs[x + I y + 6]]
```

doesn't have an intersection with the plane `z = 1`. In fact, it does not go below `z = 12`.

You can verify this by observing the behavior `z[x, y]` with planes of constant `z` with the following `Manipulate` expression.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot3D[{z[x, y], z0}, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -3, 3},AxesLabel -> Automatic],
  {{z0, 12}, 11, 15, .2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

You will also see that the contours are ellipses, not hyperbolas.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small modification to your code, is this what you are looking for ?

```
eq = Abs[x + I y - 6] + Abs[x + I y + 6] - 1
ContourPlot[eq, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True]
```

Comment: This returns a contour map of an ellipse, which is a different shape to a hyperbola that I want a definite relation of in ContourPlot. In addition, Mathematica seems to have issues plotting hyperbolas defined by the complex subset, and plots rays, circles and ellipses of the same form without any issue.